# Best way to insert a date into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a text file dump that I am processing into MySQL via PHP and the date format looks like "Jul 2012" or "Dec 2012", etc. I want to insert these into the database in a way that I could then select records in the future by date. Is there any way to convert these to the right format prior or a way to get SQL to automatically convert via a function?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, of course there is.

Comment: please provide the exact way date format looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to convert these to the right format prior or a way to get SQL to automatically convert via a function?

Keep it at the DB level with MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

For example:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Dec 2012','%b %Y');
```

Comment: This was dead on, added to my insert and its perfect. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. And thank you. Just hit 25k reputation milestone on your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember it right, the format for a datetime SQL column is

```
date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $date ) );
```

Where $date is for example Dec 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<?php
echo date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
echo date("Y.m.d") . "<br>";
echo date("Y-m-d");
?>
```

Will out put something like:

```
2009/05/11
2009.05.11
2009-05-11
```

Try something before, simplly asking...sometimes that helps

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is generate the data-time according to MySQL's standard format : `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Below is a conversion

```
$datetime = strtotime('Dec 2012');
$mysqldate = date("m/d/y", $datetime);
```